# Box.com API Usage - Get Folder Count as a service app

Tags: box

We are creating an app that is meant to be used with a Service Account in your system; another user (user-2) has authorized this app by adding our app key to their Custom Application list. How do I get this User-2's UserID, so we can impersonate him and access his files list and files, etc. We need their UserID, so we can pass the "AS-User: " Header. And can this header be set using some property from within the .NET SDK - a sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This does it for all enterprise users but you can easily put an if statement to get the user you're looking for.

```
static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        // rename the private_key.pem.example to private_key.pem and put your JWT private key in the file
        var privateKey = File.ReadAllText(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);

        var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ENTERPRISE_ID, privateKey, JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD, JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID);
        var boxJWT = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig);

        var adminToken = boxJWT.AdminToken();
        Console.WriteLine("Admin Token: " + adminToken);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var adminClient = boxJWT.AdminClient(adminToken);  // adminClient == serviceAccount

        var userDetails = await adminClient.UsersManager.GetCurrentUserInformationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("\tAdmin User Details:");
        Console.WriteLine("\tId: {0}", userDetails.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", userDetails.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("\tStatus: {0}", userDetails.Status);
        Console.WriteLine();

        var users = await adminClient.UsersManager.GetEnterpriseUsersAsync();
        users.Entries.ForEach(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", i.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", i.Status);

            if (i.Status == "active")
            {
                var userToken = boxJWT.UserToken(i.Id);
                var userClient = boxJWT.UserClient(userToken, i.Id);

                Task u = getUserItems(userClient, i.Id);
                u.Wait();                                       
            }

        });
    }

    static async Task getUserItems(BoxClient userClient, string id)
    {
        var userDetails = await userClient.UsersManager.GetCurrentUserInformationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("\nManaged User Details:");
        Console.WriteLine("\tId: {0}", userDetails.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", userDetails.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("\tStatus: {0}", userDetails.Status);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("managed users older items");
        var items = await userClient.FoldersManager.GetFolderItemsAsync("0", 500);
        items.Entries.ForEach(i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", i.Name);
        });
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ken, but our app will be running as a service and other (box.com) users will use it, so our app needs to impersonate that user so we can show them their files/folders.

So, as per your code logic above, we are going the ServiceAccount way to accomplish it.

Comment: My code is getting to this:
`code`var adminClient = boxJWT.AdminClient(adminToken, asUser: USER_ID);
var items = await adminClient.FoldersManager.GetFolderItemsAsync("0", 500); //throws permission exception`code`
1. Where I am not sure what the UserID should be, and were to find that from User-2's account? While waiting, we tried using Application ID of User-2, as that was the closest we could find to some ID.
2. Right now, the above line of code is returning me this:
"type":"error","status":403,"code":"access_denied_insufficient_permissions"